Tungsten temperature-dependent work function: help understanding the coefficients
I'm researching about tungsten work function temperature dependency.
I found the article "Temperature Dependence of the Work Function of Tungsten from Measurement of Contact Potentials by the Kelvin Method" which, for the equation:
$\omega = \omega_0 + \alpha \cdot T$
reports an $\alpha$ coefficient of $6.3 \cdot 10 ^{-5}$ Volts, and then reports no $\omega_0$ coefficient at all.
First question: is the Volts unit correct? Shouldn't it be eV since $\omega$ is usually expressed in eV?
Second: the article reports no linear coefficient at all. Is there any reliable source where I can get it from? I know it seems like a simple line fitting problem but the results reported by the article have to take into account some other effects that act as a kind of hysteresis, so I don't think it's that simple...

Okay so I had a better look at the results and the linear coefficient can be easily obtained from a line fit...  The first question still remains though.
